# Multiplicando termos da lista

Tags: python

Quero colocar a imprimir a multiplicação dos termos e gostaria de saber se existe alguma função capaz de fazer isso pra mim na linguagem Python:

```
lista = []

con = 0

while(con<5):
    n = int(input('insira um número inteiro'))

   con = con + 1

   lista.append(n)

   print('lista criada=',lis
ta)

   print('soma das listas=',sum(lista))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também pode utilizar `numpy.prod()` para obter a multiplicação de todos os elementos da lista.

Exemplo:

```
import numpy

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
resultado = numpy.prod(lista)
print(resultado)
```

Fonte: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-multiply-numbers-list-3-different-ways/

Answer (score 8):

Não há uma função própria para isso, mas há meios que te possibilitam não ter que fazer tudo na mão. Uma das formas mais simples é combinar o uso das funções [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.reduce) com [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
produto = reduce(mul, lista, 1)
print(produto)  # 120
```

Ou, fazendo de forma iterativa:

```
produto = 1
for numero in lista:
    produto *= numero
print(produto)  # 120
```

Answer (score 1):

Se estiveres utilizando o **Python 3.8** ou superior, podes fazer uso do método **[prod](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod)** da biblioteca **[math](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#module-math)**. Este método serve para calcular o produto dos elementos de um iterável.

Desta forma o código pode ser escrito...

```
from math import prod

i = 1
lista = []
while i < 5:
    lista.append(int(input(f'Insira o {i}º número inteiro: ')))
    i += 1

print(f'O produto é: {prod(lista)}')
```

...ou...

```
from math import prod

lista = list()
for i in range(1, 5):
    lista.append(int(input(f'Insira o {i}º número inteiro: ')))

print(f'O produto é: {prod(lista)}')
```